# Understanding implementation of parallel programming via threading

Tags: python, python-multithreading

[image]

Scenarion

1. Sensor is continuously sending data in an interval of 100 milliseconds ( time needs to be configurable)
2. One Thread read the data continuously from sensor and write it to a common queue
3. This process is continuous until keyboard interrupt press happens
4. Thread 2 locks queue, ( may momentarily block Thread1)
5. Read full data from queue to temp structure
6. Release the queue
7. process the data in it. It is a computational task. While performing this task. Thread 1 should keep on filling the buffer with sensor data.

I have read about threading and GIL, so step 7 cannot afford to have any loss in data sent by the sensor while performing the computational process() on thread 2.

How this can be implemented using Python?

What I started with it is

```
import queue
from threading import Thread
import queue
from queue import Queue
q = Queue(maxsize=10)
def fun1():
    
    fun2Thread = Thread(target=fun2)
    fun2Thread.start()
    while True:
      try:
        q.put(1)  
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Key Interrupt")
    fun2Thread.join()
def fun2():
    print(q.get())
def read():
    fun1Thread = Thread(target=fun1)
    fun1Thread.start()
    fun1Thread.join()
read()
```

The issue I'm facing in this is the terminal is stuck after printing 1. Can someone please guide me on how to implement this scenario?

Comment: When you start fun2 it will print whatever's on the queue then it will terminate. Also, if/when you get a KeyboardInterrupt, you will not break the *while True* loop. The net effect will be that fun1 will continually add to the queue but fun2 will only ever acquire one of the queue values. You need a strategy to keep fun2 running but also need a way to tell it to terminate. Finally, if the processes are computational in nature you should be using multiprocessing rather than multithreading

Comment: @LancelotduLac  Can you please help me a bit more starting with telling me/showing me a way to exit from the while True loop on Keyboard interrupt, and also keep fun2 running?

Comment: ie Keyboard Interrupt catches in main thread,  could you show a way ( if possible) to catch Keyboard interrupt signal in Threads ? I don't if it is possible or not, Is it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that may help.

We have a main program (driver), a client and a server. The main program manages queue construction and the starting and ending of the subprocesses.

The client sends a range of values via a queue to the client. When the range is exhausted it tells the server to terminate. There's a delay (sleep) in enqueueing the data for demonstration purposes.

Try running it once without any interrupt and note how everything terminates nicely. Then run again and interrupt (Ctrl-C) and again note a clean termination.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIG_IGN
from time import sleep


def client(q, default):
    signal(SIGINT, default)
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            sleep(0.5)
            q.put(i)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        q.put(-1)


def server(q):
    while (v := q.get()) != -1:
        print(v)


def main():
    q = Queue()
    default = signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)
    (server_p := Process(target=server, args=(q,))).start()
    (client_p := Process(target=client, args=(q, default))).start()
    client_p.join()
    server_p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT:**

Edited to ensure that the server process continues to drain the queue if the client is terminated due to a KeyboardInterrupt (SIGINT)

Comment: This is working, I have seen similar examples also, issue I'm facing is when client is also in while True ie continuously sending packets of info until program is Keyboard interrupted there is no way producer/cleint is going to stop. In this scenario after client stops with Keyboard Int, consumer/server to process remaining from buffer then stop. Can you show me how this can be done? Thank you